# Constant Hessian is not symmetric?

Tags: partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices, hessian-matrix

I have a mapping $u:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to \mathbb{R}$ of the form $$u(\mathbf{X}) = \langle \mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{C}\rangle = \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{X}^2),$$ where $\mathbf{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is non-symmetric and the angular brackets denote the matrix dot product, i.e. the sum of entries in an element-wise (or Hadamard) product. Its gradient is $$\mathbf{\nabla} u(\mathbf{X}) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{C} + \mathbf{C}\mathbf{X}^T,$$ and if my math is correct, the Hessian can be represented as $$\mathbf{H} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{\nabla}u}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{C}\otimes \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{I}\otimes \mathbf{C}^T$$ since $\frac{\partial(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{C}+\mathbf{C}\mathbf{X})}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \mathbf{C}^T\otimes \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{I}\otimes \mathbf{C}$ and $\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{X}^T} = \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}\right)^T$. However, $$\mathbf{H}^T = \mathbf{C}^T\otimes \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{I}\otimes \mathbf{C} \neq \mathbf{H}.$$ What am I missing?

Comment: I don’t see your original formula. Isn’t $u(X)=\text{tr}(X^\top X^\top C)$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, it's an equivalent formulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculations are a bit inaccurate. Since $u(X)=\operatorname{tr}(C^TX^2)$, for a small perturbation $P$, the first order term for $u(X+P)$ in $P$ is $\operatorname{tr}(C^TXP+C^TPX)=\operatorname{tr}((C^TX+XC^T)P)=\langle\operatorname{vec}(P),\operatorname{vec}(X^TC+CX^T)\rangle$. Therefore
$$
\nabla u(X)=\operatorname{vec}(X^TC+CX^T)=(C^T\otimes I+I\otimes C)K\operatorname{vec}(X)\in\mathbb R^{n^2},
$$
where $K$ denotes the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) such that $\operatorname{vec}(X^T)=K\operatorname{vec}(X)$ for every $X\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. (By the way, the gradient of a real-valued function is a coordinate vector, not a square matrix.)

Since $v\mapsto (C^T\otimes I+I\otimes C)Kv$ is linear, the Hessian of $u$ is just
$$
H=(C^T\otimes I+I\otimes C)K.
$$
This matrix is symmetric: as $K=K^T$, it is straightforward to verify that
$$
H\operatorname{vec}(X)
=\operatorname{vec}(X^TC+CX^T)
=H^T\operatorname{vec}(X)
$$
for every matrix $X$.

Answer (score 3):

By reorganizing your function as follows
$$\phi
= \mathbf{X}:\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{C}
= \mathbf{x}:(\mathbf{C}^T\otimes \mathbf{I}) 
\operatorname{vec}
\left( \mathbf{X}^T \right)
= \mathbf{x}:(\mathbf{C}^T\otimes \mathbf{I}) \mathbf{K}\mathbf{x}
$$
with the commutation matrix $\mathbf{K}$
and the notation $\mathbf{x}
=\operatorname{vec}
\left( \mathbf{X}\right)$.

The Hessian is now straightforward
$\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}^T$ with
$\mathbf{A}
=(\mathbf{C}^T\otimes \mathbf{I}) \mathbf{K}$
which is clearly symmetric.